# how to import constants from another file in node.js

Tags: node.js

Node.js v16.1.0

I am trying to import constants from another js file in the same directory. But i am not being able to do so.

**constants.js**

```js
export const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';
export const MAX_THREADS = 8;
```

**solution.js**

```js
/**
 * Import constants from the constants.js file
 * 
 * Each console.log should log a separate constant
 */

import { MAX_THREADS } from "./constants.js";
```

Comment: It would be better if you copy&paste your code instead of adding a link to image. Also please explain what it does or what it doesn't do. Do you get any error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you rename your **"solution.js"** to **solution.mjs**, it will work.

The **".mjs"** signals to node engine that you are using **ES Module** System.

Also, putting  **`"type": "module"`**  in packages.json will work as well.

Answer (score 14):

You should do something like the following.

constants.js

```
const API_URL = 'http://url.com'
const MAX_THREADS = 5

exports.API_URL = API_URL
exports.MAX_THREADS = MAX_THREADS
```

solution.js

```
const { API_URL, MAX_THREADS } = require('./constants');
```

Comment: eferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/home/roshan/coderslang/task90/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///home/roshan/coderslang/task90/solution.js:7:34
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:175:25)
    at async Loader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:178:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:68:5)

Comment: try import { API_URL, MAX_THREADS } from './constants';

Answer (score 1):

> **Node.js >= v13**

You only need to follow below step be able to use **ECMAScript** modules.

Add `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`.

```
{
  ...
  "type": "module"
}
```

Comment: how do i add it

Comment: Already added in `package.json`? Can you please share your error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled ES modules? Read about it here:
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

Comment: This is the first time I am using node js. I am in ubuntu based Zorin Os. I just installed latest verison of node js. I don't know anything about it. The website that you have given I don't understand a little